# Includes Extra properties in OData without altering the payload (uri)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

Is it possible to extend the IQueryable to include extra properties which were not selected in the query without altering the payload (uri)

Right now, we can accomplish this by overriding the ApplyQuey method

```
public class EnableAdvancedQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
    {
        public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(
                 IQueryable queryable, 
                 ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
        {
            var @base = base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);
            // Visit the @base add add extra properties
        }
    }
```

This approach depends on the current implementation and it's quite complex. I'm wondering if there is any extension point where we can inject the extra properties to be included.